# AWS Lambda using S3 Trigger: Distinguish between create and update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I understand how to use S3 put request to trigger a lambda function when a new object is created in S3.

However, I want to trigger a different lambda function when I am updating a S3 object (overwriting the original object with the same key). It doesn't seem like there is a method provided to me to distinguish between create and update when choosing the trigger. How can I accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, just from the S3 event body. An update is also a PUT operation that is indistinguishable from a create PUT operation.

In theory, you could store all events and when there is a second PUT event for the same key, you know it is an update; this isn't trivial or cheap to do.